# Make "log" a synonym of "transaction-log"

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I propose making the tag [log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) a synonym of [transaction-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction-log).

Looking at existing questions, most that use [log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) have the meaning of [transaction-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction-log).

For those questions about a time-ordered, human-readable archive of activity there is [logging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) is a useless tag (as is [logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs)), but looking at the questions it does not seem to be safe simply to make this a synonym of [transaction-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction-log).

A good number (perhaps most) of the questions should be retagged using the following (mostly MySQL-specific) tags:

- [binlog](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binlog)
- [slow-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-log)
- [error-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-log)
- [archive-log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive-log)

(these tags also need usage guidance).

For example (just from the first page of questions tagged [log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log)):

1. [Rotation of bin.log file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219156/rotation-of-bin-log-file)
2. [MySQL doesn't log queries anymore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140439/mysql-doesnt-log-queries-anymore)
3. [MySQL general log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/mysql-general-log)
4. [What does "as anonymous on" means in mysql's general log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81092/what-does-as-anonymous-on-means-in-mysqls-general-log)
5. [Mysql 5.6 general log file output not showing unix timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212956/mysql-5-6-general-log-file-output-not-showing-unix-timestamp)
6. [Error Log Location?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145627/error-log-location)
7. [How to Log All mysql queries into log file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62129/how-to-log-all-mysql-queries-into-log-file)
8. [Export MySQL query log to JSON format](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96503/export-mysql-query-log-to-json-format)
9. [Out of memory in MySQL error log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198142/out-of-memory-in-mysql-error-log)
10. [Mariadb - Variable 'innodb_log_file_size' is a read only variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173789/mariadb-variable-innodb-log-file-size-is-a-read-only-variable)
11. [Data lost in MySQL InnoDB after crash](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/data-lost-in-mysql-innodb-after-crash)
12. [MySQL shutting down automatically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194103/mysql-shutting-down-automatically)
13. [Show recent select queries on Firebird database file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191957/show-recent-select-queries-on-firebird-database-file)
14. [Can a query write to the binary log BEFORE it has finished executing?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146806/can-a-query-write-to-the-binary-log-before-it-has-finished-executing)
15. [Trying to make sense of the InnoDB log file stats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182970/trying-to-make-sense-of-the-innodb-log-file-stats)
16. [MySQL "Statement may not be safe to log in statement format" warning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/mysql-statement-may-not-be-safe-to-log-in-statement-format-warning)
17. [MySQL slow query log to identify queries that scan tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177798/mysql-slow-query-log-to-identify-queries-that-scan-tables)
18. [Logging remote transactions in mariadb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173447/logging-remote-transactions-in-mariadb)
19. [Access Control not logging successful logins on MongoDB 3.4 Community](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172608/access-control-not-logging-successful-logins-on-mongodb-3-4-community)
20. [How to log who has connected to a Postgresql (PostGIS) database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167229/how-to-log-who-has-connected-to-a-postgresql-postgis-database)
21. [What is default MySQL binlog retention in AWS RDS?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/what-is-default-mysql-binlog-retention-in-aws-rds)
22. [Mysql innodb_log_buffer_size change](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164855/mysql-innodb-log-buffer-size-change)

MySQL has [a lot of logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html). Note also that the binlog is [not the same](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98097) as a transaction log.

Once this is done by people familiar with MySQL, we can look again at what is left, and what to do about [log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) and [logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs). Probably deletion, and if necessary, blacklisting.